# Help interpreting output of describe function from Hmisc package in R

Tags: r, interpretation

I'd like to ask for help regarding the summaries the describe function from the Hmisc package in R.  Specifically, I'm wondering what the "Info" and "Gmd" outputs are to the left and right of the mean output.  I apologise for violating the forum rule about the post being clear and reproducible without the image, but I don't know how to export the output of this function without including the actual image.  I've read the documentation for the describe function but can't seem to find anything on it.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image: This is an image of the output.]

Comment: Copy the text from the R console and paste it into Cross Validated text area, surrounded by three backticks. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "gmd" is the Gini mean difference while "info" is a relative measure described in the help page associated with the describe function.

You can read about these in the manual for *Hmisc*: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf. The "info" and "gmd" are described on pages 71 and 72, respectively

Comment: Thank you very much for linking me this, I'm sorry I hadn't found this sooner.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries: we all miss things when we've been working too hard. Good luck!